# Not understanding something about LiveData observer updates, View not updated until rotate

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

I'm building an app that has a series of questions in a survey, through consecutive fragments. I'm using a FAB as a "next" button, where it is only shown when the questions have been answered (via Spinners).

It is working fine when I enter values the first time and go onto the next fragment. Upon starting the next fragment the FAB is hidden as it should be, as the new spinner values have not been selected. If I go back to the previous fragment immediately, the spinners have remembered their chosen values, without storing values in bundles, and I can see through my logcat that the page is correctly considered validated and the fab should be visible, but it is not. However if I rotate the device then the fab correctly is shown as matches the unchanged validation status.

```
    2021-01-14 15:56:57.652 20185-20185/com.example.mindsetprototypev01 D/MainActivity: liveIsProgramFragment.observe: called, value=false
    start
    2021-01-14 15:58:11.047 20185-20185/com.example.mindsetprototypev01 D/MainActivity: liveIsProgramFragment.observe: called, value=true
    2021-01-14 15:58:11.205 20185-20185/com.example.mindsetprototypev01 D/MainActivity: liveValidated.observe: called, isValidated=false
    select1
    2021-01-14 15:58:22.858 20185-20185/com.example.mindsetprototypev01 D/MainActivity: liveValidated.observe: called, isValidated=false
    select2
    2021-01-14 15:58:31.638 20185-20185/com.example.mindsetprototypev01 D/MainActivity: liveValidated.observe: called, isValidated=true
    fab is visible, go to next fragment
    2021-01-14 15:58:57.911 20185-20185/com.example.mindsetprototypev01 D/MainActivity: liveIsProgramFragment.observe: called, value=true
    2021-01-14 15:58:57.930 20185-20185/com.example.mindsetprototypev01 D/MainActivity: liveValidated.observe: called, isValidated=false
    go back
    2021-01-14 15:59:17.474 20185-20185/com.example.mindsetprototypev01 D/MainActivity: liveIsProgramFragment.observe: called, value=true
    2021-01-14 15:59:17.489 20185-20185/com.example.mindsetprototypev01 D/MainActivity: liveValidated.observe: called, isValidated=true
    2021-01-14 15:59:17.533 20185-20185/com.example.mindsetprototypev01 D/MainActivity: liveValidated.observe: called, isValidated=true
    2021-01-14 15:59:17.533 20185-20185/com.example.mindsetprototypev01 D/MainActivity: liveValidated.observe: called, isValidated=true
    fab is not visible, will rotate now
    2021-01-14 16:00:59.434 20185-20185/com.example.mindsetprototypev01 D/MainActivity: liveValidated.observe: called, isValidated=true
    2021-01-14 16:00:59.434 20185-20185/com.example.mindsetprototypev01 D/MainActivity: liveIsProgramFragment.observe: called, value=true
    2021-01-14 16:00:59.691 20185-20185/com.example.mindsetprototypev01 D/MainActivity: liveValidated.observe: called, isValidated=true
    2021-01-14 16:00:59.692 20185-20185/com.example.mindsetprototypev01 D/MainActivity: liveValidated.observe: called, isValidated=true
    fab is visible
```

The reason liveValidated is getting called 3 times is that each spinner has an onItemSelectedListener that runs validation, and then I'm also calling the validation function once in onViewStateRestored.

This visibility  problem is avoided by setting the validated flag value to false just before I redo the validation upon going back to the first page. Is this how it's supposed to work? It seems a bit clumsy and seems like missing something? Thank you

```
override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onViewStateRestored: called")
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)

    mainActivity.viewModel.setCurrentFragmentValidated(false)
    mainActivity.viewModel.setCurrentFragmentValidated(validateInputs())
}
```

The flag indicating whether a fragment has been validated is stored in my ViewModel:

```
class MindsetProgramViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val isCurrentFragmentValidated: MutableLiveData<Boolean> by lazy { MutableLiveData<Boolean>() }
    fun setCurrentFragmentValidated(value: Boolean) {
        isCurrentFragmentValidated.value = value
    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: is your viewModel scoped by the activity life cycle or fragment life cycle?

Comment: Scoped to Activity, with all the question pages being Fragments within a container, with the container in the activity.

Comment: remove the `mainActivity.viewModel.setCurrentFragmentValidated(false)` in the `onViewStateRestored`  and see if the `FAB` works as expected

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, removing that line is how I had it before ie the fab not showing. When I added that line the fab is showing as desired... but I'm not sure that is the correct way to do it, none of the guides mentioned manually resetting the MutableLiveData value.

Comment: You mentioned that clearly, my bad. LiveData won't notify the observer if the value doesn't change, so if the user navigates from `Fragment1` to `Fragment2`, the value of `isCurrentFragmentValidated` is `true`. Now if he pops back to `Fragment1`, `mainActivity.viewModel.setCurrentFragmentValidated(validateInputs())` gets triggered resulting in the value `true`. Since there's no change in the value,`FAB` is not notified. But by setting the value to `false`, there's a change and hence `FAB` is notified

Comment: This is what so strange though, the LiveData validated flag shifts from false on the second fragment, back to true on the first fragment, and that's visible in the logcat:

fab is visible, go to next fragment
D/MainActivity: liveValidated.observe: called, isValidated=false
go back
D/MainActivity: liveValidated.observe: called, isValidated=true
fab is not visible, will rotate now
D/MainActivity: liveValidated.observe: called, isValidated=true

Thanks for your feedback I appreciate it.